# How to filter the php array with multiple keys

Tags: php, arrays, filter, key

I have an array with keys, I want to filter the array with multiple keys,

I want filter the array upload_wire,ticker,exchnage and Price and etc
Here the array

```
[23] => Array
        (
            [serial] => 236
            [upload_wire] => iHub
            [ticker] => PJET
            [exchange] => OTC
            [price] => 0.0022
            [displayPrice] => $0.0022
            [MarketCapFloat] => 1655072.6148
            [MarketCapString] => 1.655M
            [title] => WCVC Announces Continued EVERx CBD Sports Water Sales Growth
            [TimeFound] => 11:19:26 PM EST
            [DateFound] => Apr 29, 2019
            [url] => https://ih.advfn.com/stock-market/USOTC/priority-aviation-inc-PJET/stock-news/79573129/wcvc-announces-continued-everx-cbd-sports-water-sa
            [KeyWordsList] => {'Share': 30, 'Convert': 1, '$': 20, 'Data': 21, 'Order': 8, 'Right': 4, 'Operate': 5, 'Phase': 1, 'Result': 9, 'Agree': 2, 'Sale': 5, 'Select': 7, 'Grow': 6, 'Crypto': 5, 'Test': 8, 'Profit': 1, 'Develop': 1, 'Produce': 1, 'Make': 2, 'Enter': 5, 'Introduce': 1, 'Cannabis': 4, 'Partner': 4, 'New': 53, 'Increase': 1, 'Priority': 6, 'Research': 1, 'Made': 1}
            [timestamp] => 1556597966
            [currentPrice] => 0
            [openPrice] => 0.0007
            [previousClose] => 0.0007
            [netChange] => 0.0000
            [bid] => 0.0006
            [bidSize] => 5020000
            [ask] => 0.0008
            [askSize] => 10000
            [marketTire] => N
            [cumulativeVolume] => 0
            [otc_CumulativeVolume] => 2372789
        ),
[29] => Array
        (
            [serial] => 344
            [upload_wire] => GNW
            [ticker] => ANF
            [exchange] => NYSE
            [price] => 28.97
            [displayPrice] => $28.97
            [MarketCapFloat] => 1976000000.0
            [MarketCapString] => 1.976B
            [title] => Abercrombie & Fitch Introduces Limited-Edition Fierce Fragrance Bottle Featuring International Football Star Romelu Lukaku  NYSE:ANF
            [TimeFound] => 11:13:22 PM EST
            [DateFound] => Apr 29, 2019
            [url] => https://globenewswire.com/news-release/2019/04/29/1811281/0/en/Abercrombie-Fitch-Introduces-Limited-Edition-Fierce-Fragrance-Bottle-Featuring-International-Football-Star-Romelu-Lukaku.html
            [KeyWordsList] => {'Share': 8, 'Reveal': 1, 'Platform': 1, 'Customer': 1, 'Launch': 3, 'Transaction': 1, 'Design': 1, '$': 49, 'Data': 5, 'Right': 2, 'Team': 1, 'Operate': 1, 'Result': 1, 'Worldwide': 1, 'Select': 14, 'Success': 2, 'Exclusive': 1, 'Sign': 3, 'Positive': 1, 'Test': 1, 'Sell': 2, 'Sharing': 1, 'Produce': 1, 'Make': 2, 'Enter': 1, 'Introduce': 4, 'Partner': 1, 'Strength': 4, 'Promise': 1, 'Distribute': 2, 'New': 25, 'License': 2, 'Made': 2}
            [timestamp] => 1556597602
            [currentPrice] => 0
            [openPrice] => 14.73
            [previousClose] => 14.61
            [netChange] => 0.17
            [bid] => 14.6
            [bidSize] => 2
            [ask] => 15.24
            [askSize] => 1900
            [marketTire] => A
            [cumulativeVolume] => 5816473
            [otc_CumulativeVolume] => 2760233
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [serial] => 275
            [upload_wire] => GNWOTC
            [ticker] => ATIXF
            [exchange] => NASDAQ
            [price] => 0.268
            [displayPrice] => $0.268
            [MarketCapFloat] => 18822118.916
            [MarketCapString] => 18.822M
            [title] => AnalytixInsight Reports Annual 2018 Financial Results TSX Venture Exchange:ALY
            [TimeFound] => 11:13:17 PM EST
            [DateFound] => Apr 29, 2019
            [url] => https://globenewswire.com/news-release/2019/04/25/1810180/0/en/AnalytixInsight-Reports-Annual-2018-Financial-Results.html
            [KeyWordsList] => {'Share': 7, 'Reduce': 1, 'Platform': 4, 'Strong': 1, 'Customer': 8, 'Launch': 4, 'Transaction': 4, 'Collaborate': 1, 'Design': 1, 'Secondary': 1, '$': 61, 'Improve': 3, 'Data': 8, 'Order': 1, 'Right': 1, 'Operate': 6, 'Result': 12, 'Worldwide': 3, 'Agree': 5, 'Select': 16, 'Success': 6, 'Grow': 3, 'Major': 1, 'Strategic': 2, 'Sign': 3, 'Merge': 1, 'Test': 1, 'Develop': 13, 'Provide': 7, 'Produce': 1, 'Make': 2, 'Enter': 5, 'Partner': 2, 'Promise': 1, 'Distribute': 8, 'New': 26, 'Increase': 4, 'License': 2, 'Research': 9, 'Client': 2, 'Achieve': 2, 'Made': 1}
            [timestamp] => 1556597597
            [currentPrice] => 0
            [openPrice] => 0.2773
            [previousClose] => 0.273
            [netChange] => -0.02738
            [bid] => 0.2627
            [bidSize] => 2500
            [ask] => 2.64
            [askSize] => 100
            [marketTire] => D
            [cumulativeVolume] => 0
            [otc_CumulativeVolume] => 900
        )
```

I Have tried with below code, Now I want filter with Multiple keys for expample, Exchange and Price, I want to filter OTC and NYSE

```
function filter_by_value ($array, $index, $value){ 
                        if(is_array($array) && count($array)>0)  
                        { 
                            foreach(array_keys($array) as $key){ 
                                $temp[$key] = $array[$key][$index]; 

                                if ($temp[$key] == $value){ 
                                    $newarray[$key] = $array[$key]; 
                                } 
                            } 
                          } 
                      return $newarray; 
                    } 

                    $nResult = filter_by_value ($nResult, 'exchange', 'OTC');
```

Excepted Result

```
[23] => Array
        (
            [serial] => 236
            [upload_wire] => iHub
            [ticker] => PJET
            [exchange] => OTC
            [price] => 0.0022
            [displayPrice] => $0.0022
            [MarketCapFloat] => 1655072.6148
            [MarketCapString] => 1.655M
            [title] => WCVC Announces Continued EVERx CBD Sports Water Sales Growth
            [TimeFound] => 11:19:26 PM EST
            [DateFound] => Apr 29, 2019
            [url] => https://ih.advfn.com/stock-market/USOTC/priority-aviation-inc-PJET/stock-news/79573129/wcvc-announces-continued-everx-cbd-sports-water-sa
            [KeyWordsList] => {'Share': 30, 'Convert': 1, '$': 20, 'Data': 21, 'Order': 8, 'Right': 4, 'Operate': 5, 'Phase': 1, 'Result': 9, 'Agree': 2, 'Sale': 5, 'Select': 7, 'Grow': 6, 'Crypto': 5, 'Test': 8, 'Profit': 1, 'Develop': 1, 'Produce': 1, 'Make': 2, 'Enter': 5, 'Introduce': 1, 'Cannabis': 4, 'Partner': 4, 'New': 53, 'Increase': 1, 'Priority': 6, 'Research': 1, 'Made': 1}
            [timestamp] => 1556597966
            [currentPrice] => 0
            [openPrice] => 0.0007
            [previousClose] => 0.0007
            [netChange] => 0.0000
            [bid] => 0.0006
            [bidSize] => 5020000
            [ask] => 0.0008
            [askSize] => 10000
            [marketTire] => N
            [cumulativeVolume] => 0
            [otc_CumulativeVolume] => 2372789
        ),
[29] => Array
        (
            [serial] => 344
            [upload_wire] => GNW
            [ticker] => ANF
            [exchange] => NYSE
            [price] => 28.97
            [displayPrice] => $28.97
            [MarketCapFloat] => 1976000000.0
            [MarketCapString] => 1.976B
            [title] => Abercrombie & Fitch Introduces Limited-Edition Fierce Fragrance Bottle Featuring International Football Star Romelu Lukaku  NYSE:ANF
            [TimeFound] => 11:13:22 PM EST
            [DateFound] => Apr 29, 2019
            [url] => https://globenewswire.com/news-release/2019/04/29/1811281/0/en/Abercrombie-Fitch-Introduces-Limited-Edition-Fierce-Fragrance-Bottle-Featuring-International-Football-Star-Romelu-Lukaku.html
            [KeyWordsList] => {'Share': 8, 'Reveal': 1, 'Platform': 1, 'Customer': 1, 'Launch': 3, 'Transaction': 1, 'Design': 1, '$': 49, 'Data': 5, 'Right': 2, 'Team': 1, 'Operate': 1, 'Result': 1, 'Worldwide': 1, 'Select': 14, 'Success': 2, 'Exclusive': 1, 'Sign': 3, 'Positive': 1, 'Test': 1, 'Sell': 2, 'Sharing': 1, 'Produce': 1, 'Make': 2, 'Enter': 1, 'Introduce': 4, 'Partner': 1, 'Strength': 4, 'Promise': 1, 'Distribute': 2, 'New': 25, 'License': 2, 'Made': 2}
            [timestamp] => 1556597602
            [currentPrice] => 0
            [openPrice] => 14.73
            [previousClose] => 14.61
            [netChange] => 0.17
            [bid] => 14.6
            [bidSize] => 2
            [ask] => 15.24
            [askSize] => 1900
            [marketTire] => A
            [cumulativeVolume] => 5816473
            [otc_CumulativeVolume] => 2760233
        )
```

Comment: Filter how? Removing items? Keeping items? Filter on key name or value? Please edit your question to include a proper explanation and show us what the expected result is and what your current code gives you.

Comment: filter an array with key and Values, an array contains all key I need to filter Key and Values for example  I need to filter EXchange OTC and NYSE, as shown in excepted result

Comment: And how are you going to filter for price? or any other key-value?

Comment: @Rahul Yes I want too filter Price also, can you suggest me

Comment: All filter's criteria must match or any one of them should match? Once check my answer! I modified your filter Criteria Array.

Comment: @Rahul all of them match like in SQL AND query

Comment: @David As  per my understanding, I created the snippet below, please have a look.

Comment: @Rahul In filter for Price between range like 25 to 30 values list of array should show for example in array between 25 to 30 price values list alone,  can you suggest me

Comment: write and if statement with > and < condition in foreach loop

Comment: @Rahul with both exchange and price keys..filters in that particular price between range both conditions should satisfy  can you suggest me a code.....

Comment: $allowedVals = ['exchange' => ["NASDAQ"], 'upload_wire' => ["iHub"]];
$result      = [];
foreach ($nResult as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($allowedVals as $key1 => $value1) {
        if (isset($value[$key1]) && count(array_intersect([$value[$key1]], $value1))) {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }else{
            unset($result[$key]);
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Rahul But only last filter upload_wire is filtered we required both in and condition like NASDAQ and iHub should be filtered... your suggested code only  satisfy any one condition at a time...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the structure you want to filter with

```
$allowedVals = ['exchange' => ["OTC", "NYSE"], 'price' => [28.97,0.268]];
$result      = [];
foreach ($nResult as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($allowedVals as $key1 => $value1) {
        if (isset($value[$key1]) && count(array_intersect([$value[$key1]], $value1))) {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }else{
            unset($result[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7c720b3ceddbad4f307144990b7f83dc8f9d389f)